# Blosum matrix computation with X%

Tags: sequence-alignment

Why does the answers to the problem found in the referenced pdf, differ from my calculation below? ***I am trying to understand the math from this pdf*** from an online tutorial I am reading and my own math does not give the same result: Can someone help derive their answer or confirm mine?

http://www.cs.columbia.edu/4761/assignments/assignment1/reference1.pdf
*On page 13*, **I am trying to figure out how the weighted values are determined**:

**For example C_LL**: 2.33 means the construct is [L_1   (L_2a L_2b)  L] and the center block is being counted as 1/3 for each so we get 4*(1/3) + 1 = 2.33 but the L_2a to L_2b i.e., the inside the block is not counted that should make it 2.66 right?

**For C_LV**: here there is obviously 4*1/3+1 and now the internal would be 2*1/3 which sums to 3 not 3.33. And now the internal one is counted.

I am confused. Any help?